# JS - canvas translate didn't translate shooting function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My 2D shooter is supposed to fire bullets from the player in the direction of the cursor. But when the canvas centers the player to the middle of the screen, the bullets don't fire towards the cursor, they behave differently depending on the location of the player. How can I fix this bug? Here is the source code https://pastebin.com/Cxdx5Pw9 as well as some code taken from the file

```
    b.save();
    b.translate(-p1.x + canvas.width / 2, -p1.y + canvas.height / 2);
    b.clearRect(p1.x - (canvas.width/2), p1.y - (canvas.height/2), canvas.width, canvas.height);
    b.fillStyle = "#f03a47";
    b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    p1.draw();
    p1.fire();


    b.restore();
```

After I drew the player within the translation and outside of it, I found out that my shooting function was choosing its direction based on the player if the canvas was never translated to begin with (this can be seen by un-commenting "p1.draw();" at line 318 and then executing the file). So is there a way to tell my shooting function to choose a direction based on the centered player rather than the free moving player?

I've also tried calling the shooting function after the canvas.restore() but with equally bad results, giving me the correct direction, but a wrong origin.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my problem was that while I calculated for the direction of the bullet, I forgot to include the offset of the canvas. After adding that, the problem went away.